# How to handle groups of data in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Early in my program I have the program generate a vector, 9 elements at a time. Each of these groups of 9 are related data. Later on I want to handle each 9 groups in one go (e.g. print them out 9 per line).

How should I go about this? My attempt:

```
 for (unsigned int i = 0; i < solutions.size()/9; i++)
 {
  cout << i << ": " << solutions[0+ i*9] << " " << solutions[1+ i*9] << " " << solutions[2 + i*9] << " " << solutions[3+ i*9] << " " << solutions[4+ i*9] << " " << solutions[5 + i*9] << " " << solutions[6+ i*9] << " " << solutions[7+ i*9] << " "<< solutions[8 + i*9] << endl;
  cout << endl;
 }
```

I've obviously messed up here somewhere. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using a struct.

```
struct elems {
    elements elems[9];
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const elems& elems) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
        out << elems.elems[i];
    return out;
}
std::vector<elems> solutions;
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use vectors of vector ?

```
vector< vector <int> > solution;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < solutions.size(); i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<9; j++) {
       cout << solution[i][j] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix, you just need a temporary indexing variable and increment it throughout the loop while incrementing your main index by nine each time.

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < solutions.size(); i += 9) {
   int j = i;
  std::cout << i << ": " << solutions[j++] << " " << solutions[j++] << " " << solutions[j++] << " " << solutions[j++] << " " << solutions[j++] << " " << solutions[j++] << " " << solutions[j++] << " " << solutions[j++] << " "<< solutions[j++] << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @Andy: If this is the accepted answer, then you might want to mark it as such so people browsing can see has been answered.